# How FunctionConvexity is implemented in Wolfram Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, mathematical-optimization, implementation-details

I am wondering how [`FunctionConvexity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionConvexity.html) was implemented in Wolfram Mathematica.

I am trying to prove the convexity of the function $A(v)$:

$$ A(v) = -\dfrac{k-1}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{v_i}}, $$

where $k\geq 2$ is some integer constant and $1 \leq v_i \leq k-1$.

The function is easily passed in Mathematica as convex,meaning that it somehow passes the following condition:

$$ f(t x +(1-t)y)\leq t f(x)+(1-t)f(y) ,$$

where $0\leq t\leq 1.$

However, I am having trouble verifying it by hand.

A similar question is also up on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4332759/prove-that-the-function-is-convex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my  guess (Many years of teaching stand behind.). Indeed,

```
FunctionConvexity[{-(3 - 1)/Sum[1/v[j], {j, 1, 3}], 
v[1] >= 1 && v[2] >= 1 && v[3] >= 1&& v[1] <= 2 && v[2] <= 2 && v[3] <= 2}, {v[1], v[2], v[3]}]
```

results in `1` which means the function is convex on  the cube. I think the command does not check the definition of convexity here, but uses the  nonnegativity of its Laplacian by

```
Minimize[{Laplacian[-(3 - 1)/Sum[1/v[j], {j, 1, 3}], {v[1], v[2], 
v[3]}], {v[1], v[2], v[3]} >= 1&& {v[1], v[2], v[3]} <=2}, {v[1], v[2], v[3]}]
```

> `{4/9, {v[1] -> 2, v[2] -> 2, v[3] -> 2}}`

The same in other dimensions.

Addition. I think the above is true, however the general approach is more complicated (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) for info):

```
m = ResourceFunction["HessianMatrix"][-(3 - 1)/
Sum[1/v[j], {j, 1, 3}], {v[1], v[2], v[3]}];
Minimize[{{a, b, c} . m.{a, b, c}, {v[1], v[2], v[3]} >= 1 && {v[1], v[2], v[3]} <= 
2}, {a, b, c}]
```

> `{Piecewise[{{0, Inequality[1, LessEqual, v[2], LessEqual, 2] && Inequality[1, LessEqual, v[1], LessEqual, 2] &&  Inequality[1, LessEqual, v[3], LessEqual, 2]}}, Infinity],  {a -> Piecewise[{{0, Inequality[1, LessEqual, v[2], LessEqual, 2] && Inequality[1, LessEqual, v[1], LessEqual, 2] &&  Inequality[1, LessEqual, v[3], LessEqual, 2]}}, Indeterminate],  b -> Piecewise[{{0, Inequality[1, LessEqual, v[2], LessEqual, 2] && Inequality[1, LessEqual, v[1], LessEqual, 2] &&  Inequality[1, LessEqual, v[3], LessEqual, 2]}}, Indeterminate],  c -> Piecewise[{{0, Inequality[1, LessEqual, v[2], LessEqual, 2] && Inequality[1, LessEqual, v[1], LessEqual, 2] &&  Inequality[1, LessEqual, v[3], LessEqual, 2]}}, Indeterminate]}}`

and this means the convexity.

Edit. My guess concerning the Laplacian is not true as $x^2-y^2$ demonstrates. I missed subharmonic and convex functions:  explanation, but not  justification. The gradient or the Hessian matrix can be used to this end.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not familiar with the concept of Laplacian, I am reading about it at this very moment. Could be a valid approach for analytical proof? Also, please note that there is a similar question where we are looking for analytical proof on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4332759/prove-that-the-function-is-convex).

Comment: I familiarised myself with a concept. However, I guess that the non-negativity of Laplacian implies that the function is element-wise convex. I am not sure that we can conclude that the function is convex over its domain using this method. Please, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Oleh: You are right. The non-negativity of the Laplacian does not imply the convexity. A simple example is $x^2-y^2$.